# How to avoid default secret being attached to ServiceAccount?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to create a service account with either no secrets or just secret I specify and the kubelet always seems to be attaching the default secret no matter what.

#### Service Account definition

```
apiVersion: v1
automountServiceAccountToken: false
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: test
secrets:
  - name: default-token-4pbsm
```

**Submit**

```
$ kubectl create -f service-account.yaml
serviceaccount "test" created
```

**Get**

```
$ kubectl get -o=yaml serviceaccount test
apiVersion: v1
automountServiceAccountToken: false
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2017-05-30T12:25:30Z
  name: test
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "31414"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/serviceaccounts/test
  uid: 122b0643-4533-11e7-81c6-42010a8a005b
secrets:
- name: default-token-4pbsm
- name: test-token-5g3wb
```

As you can see above the `test-token-5g3wb` was automatically created & attached to the service account without me specifying it.

As far as I understand the `automountServiceAccountToken` only affects mounting of those secrets to a pod which was launched via that service account. (?)

Is there any way I can avoid that default secret being ever created and attached?

#### Versions

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.4", GitCommit:"d6f433224538d4f9ca2f7ae19b252e6fcb66a3ae", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-05-19T20:41:24Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.4", GitCommit:"d6f433224538d4f9ca2f7ae19b252e6fcb66a3ae", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-05-19T18:33:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of `automountServiceAccountToken` is right it is for pod that will be launched.

The automatic token addition is done by Token controller. Even if you edit the config to delete the token it will be added again.

> You must pass a service account private key file to the token controller in the controller-manager by using the **`--service-account-private-key-file`** option. The private key will be used to sign generated service account tokens. Similarly, you must pass the corresponding public key to the kube-apiserver using the **`--service-account-key-file`** option. The public key will be used to verify the tokens during authentication.

Above is taken from k8s [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/service-accounts-admin/#token-controller). So try not passing those flags, but not sure how to do that. But I not recommending doing that.

Also [this doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/#service-account-tokens) you might helpful.